# Undefined on node console

Tags: jquery, node.js

[image]

I am trying to do a put request but when ever I do one I get an undefined on the console and also I do get a 200 status code on PUT but my data will not update

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Adil@123',
  database: 'movies'

});
mysqlConnection.connect(err=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log('It was not successful \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
  } else {
    console.log('Its a success');
  }
  });
 //  Collecting all the movies from the movielist
  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 // Finding a movie based on the `idmovielist` number
   app.get('/movielist',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err, rows,fields) =>{
    if (!err) {
      res.send(rows);
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });

  // Delting a movie
   app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
  // Inserting a movie
  app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
    //console.log("movielist/addMovie : ",req.body);
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (`idmovielist`,`name`,`thumnail_path`,`description`,`language_released`,`year_released`) VALUES ('"+req.body.idmovielist+"', '"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.thumnail_path+"', '"+req.body.description+"', '"+req.body.year_released+"', '"+req.body.language_released+"')",
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});

app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  let update = req.body;
  console.log(update.name);
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = '?', thumnail_path = '?', description = '?', year_released = '?', language_released = '?' WHERE idmovielist = ?",
  [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

// localhost:3000
app.listen(3000,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = app;

$(function() {
  $.ajax({
      method:"GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
        const rowText = "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\"  class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
          $("#movies").append(rowText);
        });

renderMovieList('movies');
  function renderMovieList(){
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $('#movies').empty();
    $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
    const rowText = "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\"  class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
      $("#movies").append(rowText);
    });
    }
  });
}
  $("#movieAdded").click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let mydata = {
      idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    displayMovie(mydata);

    $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#newForm").toggle();
  });

  $("#updateMovie").on("click", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);

    $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#updateForm").toggle();
});

function getOneMovie(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist" + id,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
      $("#updateForm").show();
    }
  });
}

function displayMovie(mydata) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: mydata,
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
      renderMovieList();
}
});
}

function loadButtons() {
              $(".editMovie").click(function (a) {
                  getOneMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });

              $(".deleteMovie").click(function (a) {
                  deleteMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });
          }

loadButtons();
function putMovie(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/12",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      getOneMovie();
    }
  });
}



function deleteMovie() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/4",
    method: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}

}
})

});
```

So this is my app.js and mycrud.js above the front end and back end I had put single quotation marks on all the coulmn names I really do not know where this undefined is coming from is one of my column names undefined

Comment: Try adding some context in your `console.log()` calls, like `console.log("In putMovie", data)`. Then you'll know where it's coming from.

Comment: You have lots of `console.log()` calls, there's no way for us to know which ones are causing this.

Comment: putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data); //here you pass  2 params                                                             
                                      function  putMovie(data) // here you just receive 1 param

Answer (score 0):

`app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
      let update = req.body;
      console.log(update.name);//where is update defined?
      mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = '?', thumnail_path = '?', description = '?', year_released = '?', language_released = '?' WHERE idmovielist = ?",
      [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id], function (err, results) {
        if (!err) {
          res.send("Movie list is updated");
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });`

Your question / code is a bit confusing so I am not 100% sure that I am answering it correctly but it looks like update.name is not defined. When doing a put request you might want to log the request or even the answer on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `console.log(update.name)`. 
Let me explain the reason for this problem. Lets take a look at the following

```
putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);
```

The above one is your calling function, here you can see that two parameters are passing.

But in your called function

```
function putMovie(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/12",
        method: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          getOneMovie();
       }
  });
}
```

In this function definition you used only one argument. So the problem is when you called this function you passing **data** as your second parameter. But it never used in function definition.

```
function putMovie("",data) {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/12",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
....
```

If you do like this you can pass data to your api.

Comment: so for data: what do I put

Comment: so in the parenthesis should I put "movieId",data

Comment: @Nihil Unni  function putMovie( "movieId",data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/12" + "movieId",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      getOneMovie();
    }
  });
} like this

Comment: app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  let update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = '"+update.name+"', thumnail_path = '"+update.thumnail_path+"', description = '"+update.description+"', year_released = '"+update.year_released+"', language_released = '"+update.language_released+"' WHERE idmovielist = '"+update.idmovielist+"'",
   function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}); I put this in my app.js

Comment: the only change you have to do is, make the data as second parameter in function definition.which solves the error that printing undefined in console